# Prevent renaming of file from another binary on Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-io

I am working with multiple processes that write to the same directory.
I have a directory dir1/

My process creates a file a.txt under dir1/. However the other process creates a-temp1.txt and renames it to a.txt. I don't have control over the other process since that code comes from a library. Can I prevent a-temp.txt from being renamed?

Comment: Do the processes run as different users?  Your best bet might be to have them run as different users,  and use file permissions to prevent the other user from overwriting it.  This might be tangential to the real issue though, which I don't think there's enough info here to help with.

Comment: No, the processes run as the same user. And I can't change this.

Comment: I'm having a very hard time believing that a usable system is going to come out of solving the problem this way.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do that the other process can't undo. Your best hope (other than changing your program to work sanely) is that the other process doesn't try too hard to do the rename. That is, it tries the simple approach and gives up if that fails.

In particular, you can set the `UF_IMMUTABLE` flag on either file and that will prevent one from being renamed to replace the other. You can set the flag using [`chflags()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chflags.2.html). Using Cocoa, you could also use `[someURL setResourceValue:@YES forKey:NSURLIsUserImmutableKey error:NULL]`.

Keep in mind that you won't be able to change the file in any other way, either, until that flag is removed. If the other process is determined to rename the file, it has permission to remove the flag just like your process does.

Also keep in mind that a system such as this is inherently race-prone.

You really ought to use separate names for the files, or separate directories, or ditch that library that doesn't give you the control you need.

Comment: I think this a step forward. But I would still like a-temp.txt to remain in the directory. The other process deletes it if the rename failed. Any way to prevent deletion of that file? Please note that I don't have control over when the file is created. I agree that the library is inherently race-prone. I unfortunately can't make changes to it and I am trying to work around it to solve the race condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it unlikely will solve your problem. I strongly suspect this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and almost certainly the correct solution is to redesign some part of this system entirely, probably by changing your file names, using unique temporary files, moving to another directory, or reworking the usage of the library (libraries only do what callers tell them to do; and libraries are just code anyway). You shouldn't try to defeat another process; you're all working for the same user.

All that said, sure, you can prevent your own userid from renaming over file. Just deny yourself permission. <strike>You can modify the file:</strike>

```
chmod 400 a.txt
```

That says that you can read the file but may not write it. However, if you already have an open file handle, you may continue to use it (so you can keep writing to the file, even though another process running as the same user may not).

Similarly, you may change permissions on the directory:

```
chmod 500 .
```

This would prevent the rename because file names are kept in the directory.

Comment: Nope.  The `chmod 400` doesn't work.  Just tried it.  `rename()` will happily deep six the file and replace it with another.

Comment: Interesting; `mv` won't; it must be checking at another level. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: the 500 also would not work since creation (which is a write operation on the directory) would not work. I wish I could redesign/rework this system but unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chflags()` on an HFS+ (Mac OS X) file system to set the `UF_APPEND` attribute.  (Do a `man 2 chflags`.)  That will permit appending to the file, but not deleting or renaming, even by the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Set the user immutable flag `chflags(...,uchg`). This will keep the other process from changing your file unless it takes action to clear the bit.  Of course I don't know how the other process will react to you putting things in it's way, but that wasn't the question.